# Iterate over a badly formed set with python

Tags: python, set, iteration

I've got a batch of PDF documents with the following metadata property:
Language: `set([NL,DE,FR,EN])`

I want to iterate these values but it outputs each char like:

```
s
e
t
(
[
...
E
N
,
]
)
```

My guess is that the set is missing quotes. `set(["NL","FR","DE","EN"])`

Is there a way so I can still iterate the values? If so, I could rewrite the property.

Comment: Even if `set` had quotes, you'd still have the problem of safely evaluating the string.  Are there any constraints here?  e.g. is the possible set of tokens known?  Are they all only 2 characters wide?  etc.

Comment: They are all two characters wilde and in uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for lang in re.findall("[A-Z]{2}",metadata_text):
    print lang
```

I guess maybe?

alternatively

```
for lang in metadata_text[5:-2].split(","):
    print lang
```